# Not seeing JavaScript value change until clicked

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I'm writing a python script with Selenium. I'm trying to input a value to 'tel' type input and I get the error that **{ElementNotInteractableException}Message: element not interactable** when I run `version_element.send_keys('1')`. The solution I came up with was to run `driver.execute_script("document.getElementById('numVersions').value='1';")`. This runs without error. However, I cannot see the change update on the webpage until I click the input box, at which point it will update.

Does anyone have any idea how I can force it to update?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you share some more code or the URL you are working on?

Comment: Sorry, yeah i figured out that if i entered the info how I was but then moved up one level of the dom if I simulated a click there then it updated. Thanks!